# Using RNN in R with factorial input variables

Tags: r, recurrent-neural-network

In [`rnn`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rnn) package in R, the example shows how to train a RNN with numeric input variables.

The example code is:

```
library('rnn')

# create training numbers
set.seed(1)
X1 = sample(0:127, 7000, replace=TRUE)
X2 = sample(0:127, 7000, replace=TRUE)

# create training response numbers
Y <- X1 + X2

# convert to binary
X1 <- int2bin(X1, length=8)
X2 <- int2bin(X2, length=8)
Y  <- int2bin(Y,  length=8)

# create 3d array: dim 1: samples; dim 2: time; dim 3: variables
X <- array( c(X1,X2), dim=c(dim(X1),2) )

# train the model
model <- trainr(Y=Y,
                X=X,
                learningrate   =  0.1,
                hidden_dim     = 10,
                start_from_end = TRUE )
```

In the above example, `X1` and `X2` are numerical variables.

How can I train a RNN model in R if the input variables are factor?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

have you tried coercing the factor to numeric:

```
Y <- as.numeric(Y)
```

For predicted values you would want to round them and then apply the levels again:

```
pred <- round(pred)

pred <- as.factor(pred, labels = c(...))
```

Comment: In fact, I did not try, but from some external resources, it seems to have problem :-( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469835/one-hot-encoding-for-machine-learning

Comment: rnn is not one hot, that is simply an example

Comment: one-hot is a next step. The answer in the link I posted above is talking about converting factor to numeric variables and its effects.

Comment: anyway, I will try and post the results here.

Comment: Hi, I did that and observe an interest thing: the RNN now will tend to predict with extreme unbalanced output, i.e. for binary classification, RNN tend to predict everything as positive (or negative), but rarely it give a mixed prediction.

Comment: have you tried tuning the hyperparameters, learningrate, epochs, etc.?

Comment: Yeah, I am doing that. Of course I cannot try all the combinations. Still in progress.