# Label scalar into one hot in Tensorr flow code?

Tags: tensorflow

Can some one please guide me that what is meant by conversion from scalar to one hot? and what is the purpose of `labels_dense.shape[0]` and at the end why label one hot.flat is equal to one?
    `def dense_to_one_hot(labels_dense, num_classes=10):
    """Convert class labels from scalars to one-hot vectors"""
    num_labels = labels_dense.shape[0]
    index_offset = np.arange(num_labels) * num_classes
    labels_one_hot = np.zeros((num_labels, num_classes))
    labels_one_hot.flat[index_offset + labels_dense.ravel()] = 1
    return labels_one_hot`

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find this answer describing how one hot encoding works in machine learning helpful:
[One Hot Encoding for Machine learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469835/one-hot-encoding-for-machine-learning)

Answer (score 0):

I came across that same [function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/7c36309c37b04843030664cdc64aca2bb7d6ecaa/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py#L221) and wrote a simpler one to understand. I am using the digits 0 to 4 which represent 5 classes.

What is the purpose of labels_dense.shape[0] ?

It returns the number of labels which is '10' in this example.

What does this code mean ?

```
labels_one_hot.flat[index_offset + labels_dense.ravel()] = 1
```

It is logic to put '1' in the correct position as you can see in the output. It is just calculating the position from the beginning of the entire one-hot representation.

So to represent the digit '0' as a one-hot vector the 45th position should be'1'. This corresponds to the 0th element of the last vector.

So

```
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

is the one-hot representation for the digit '0' when we have 5 classes.

```
def onehot():

    labels_dense = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,3,4,3,2,1,0])

    print('Shape of labels_dense is ' + str(labels_dense.shape))

    index_offset = numpy.arange(10) * 5

    print('Index offset is \n' + str(index_offset))

    labels_one_hot = numpy.zeros((10, 5))

    print('index_offset + labels_dense.ravel() is\n' + str(index_offset + labels_dense.ravel()))

    labels_one_hot.flat[index_offset + labels_dense.ravel()] = 1

    print('One-hot labels are ' + str(labels_one_hot))
```

Output is this.

```
Shape of labels_dense is (10,)
Index offset is 
[ 0  5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45]
index_offset + labels_dense.ravel() is
[ 1  7 13 19 23 29 33 37 41 45]
One-hot labels are 

[[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```